# MySql multiple connection issue

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli

I am facing following issue sometimes while running an application in codeigniter:

Message:  mysqli::real_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections

I get this error randomly.Anyone having solution on it?

```
 $db['default'] = array( 'dsn' => '', 
                         'hostname' => 'localhost', 
                         'username' => 'root', 
                         'password' => '', 
                         'database' => 'BirthdayOwl', 
                         'dbdriver' => 'mysqli', 
                         'dbprefix' => '',
                         'pconnect' => FALSE, 
                         'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'development'),
                         cache_on' => FALSE, 
                         'cachedir' => '', 
                         'char_set' => 'utf8', '
                         dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci', 
                         'swap_pre' => '', 
                         'encrypt' => FALSE, 
                         'compress' => FALSE,
                         'stricton' => FALSE,
                         'failover' => array(), 
                         'save_queries' => TRUE );
```

Comment: show your database config array

Comment: $db['default'] = array(
                'dsn' => '',   'hostname' => 'localhost',  'username' => 'root',  'password' => '',  'database' => 'BirthdayOwl', 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
                'dbprefix' => '','pconnect' => FALSE,  'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'development'), 'cache_on' => FALSE,  'cachedir' => '',  'char_set' => 'utf8',   'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',   'swap_pre' => '',    'encrypt' => FALSE,   'compress' => FALSE,'stricton' => FALSE,'failover' => array(),
           'save_queries' => TRUE
            );

Comment: @SwatiB re edit your question rather putting code in comment by clicking on the edit button

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the value of `max_connections` in your MySQL configuration file. Possible location of file will be: `/etc/my.cnf`.

On the file increase the value of max_connections system variable:

```
[mysqld]
set-variable=max_connections=1000
```

you can also turn off persistent connection from MySQL.

```
[MySQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
mysql.allow_persistent=Off
```

This will help you. Let me know if it not works

Comment: Thanks for reply.But i have tried above things.It is of no use still i am getting an error

Comment: Have you restarted your mysql server.?

Comment: can you please fire this command and share output. `show processlist;`

Comment: +-------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id    | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+-------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 66197 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
+-------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Okay. It seems like good. next check, Can you please share your query when you got this error.?, It might be query issue.

Comment: can you tell me how you analayzed that its good and its happening because of query?

Comment: so don't know which query is responsible for it

Comment: See most of the time when you have many queries in sleep mode and too many connections active in database at that time you got this error. So when you do `show processlist` you came to know active connection. In your case processlist gives pretty much good result. Hence there will be some issue in one of your query. So you have to share that proper query whenever this happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase connection limit by setting 'max_connections'. But everything has some limit. You can set 'max_connections' that will consume your 100% memory. If you set bigger number, that will create chaos.

You should use `'pconnect' => TRUE` to reduce multiple connection. This configuration will open persistence connection.

I recommend you to use proper mix of 'max_connections' with `'pconnect' => TRUE`

Let me know still you are facing problem.